# How do i convert this code from Dataweave 1 to Dataweave 2

Tags: mule-studio, dataweave

I have to convert some code from dataweave 1 to dataweave 2 but I'm not sure how to convert this patch of code. The answers I found online are confusing

I'm not sure if these two maps are syntaxed the right way, or the syntax for filtering then mapping. I know you have to convert flowVars to vars

```
flowVars.referenceDataResponse.resultSets filter $.schemaSequenceNumber == "TRESIDENCE_TYPE" map (resultSets,indexOfResultSets) -> {
   (resultSets.resultSet map (resultSet,indexOfResultSet) -> {
      residenceType:resultSet[indexOfResultSet].data
    } )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really give more context, like inputs, expected output and the directives of the script but this is a literal translation, with output set to application/java because of lack of anything else:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java  
---
vars.referenceDataResponse.resultSets filter $.schemaSequenceNumber == "TRESIDENCE_TYPE" map (resultSets, indexOfResultSets) -> {
  (resultSets.resultSet map (resultSet, indexOfResultSet) -> {
    residenceType: resultSet[indexOfResultSet].data
  })
}
```

No way to know if it works for you, given that there is no test data.

Answer (score 0):

**Alejandro,**
I have Posted sample data, may help to test your suggested conversion solution and I have assumed resultSet is an object with two attribute. You may improve the data to cater your suggested solution

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

var  arr = 
referenceDataResponse: {
  resultSets : 
      [
       {
       id: 1,
       schemaSequenceNumber :"TRESIDENCE_TYPE",
       resultSet: [{residenceType: "one"},{residenceType: "two"},{residenceType: "three"}]
       },
       {
       id: 2,
       schemaSequenceNumber :"TRESIDENCE_TYPE2",
       resultSet:[{residenceType: "one"},{residenceType: "two"},{residenceType: "three"}]
       },
       {
       id: 3,
       schemaSequenceNumber :"TRESIDENCE_TYPE3",
       resultSet:[{residenceType: "one"},{residenceType: "two"},{residenceType: "three"}]
      }
     ] 
}

---

arr.referenceDataResponse.resultSets filter $.schemaSequenceNumber == "TRESIDENCE_TYPE" map (resultSets, indexOfResultSets) -> {
  (resultSets.resultSet map (resultSet, indexOfResultSet) -> {
    residenceType: resultSet.residenceType
  })
}
```